# PHP - Display XML attributes in HTML select box (via AJAX and JSON)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, json

I've got an assignment to create a small web application that lets the user upload a GPX file (XML). It looks like this:

```
<gpx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0" version="1.0" creator="GPSBabel - http://www.gpsbabel.org" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd">
<time>2008-10-17T20:11:41Z</time>
<bounds minlat="48.063300000" minlon="8.567683333" maxlat="48.765550000" maxlon="10.039016667"/>
   <trk>
   <name>PRESALTTRK</name>
   <desc>
IGCHDRS~HFFXA500~HFPLTPilotincharge:~HPCM2Crew2:~HFGTYGliderType:SF25C2000~HFGIDGliderID:D-KFEL~HFDTM100GPSDatum:WGS84~HFRFWFirmwareVersion:Flarm04.04~HFRHWHardwareVersion:Flarm06~HFFTYFRType:Flarm~HFGPSu-blox:LEA-4P,16,8191~HFPRSPressAltSensor:Intersema MS5534B,8191~HFCCLCompetitionClass:Motorsegler~HFCIDCompetitionID:~
   </desc>
      <trkseg>
         <trkpt lat="48.063300000" lon="8.567683333">
            <ele>675.000000</ele>
            <time>2008-09-11T16:22:01Z</time>
         </trkpt>
         <trkpt lat="48.063783333" lon="8.568383333">
            <ele>675.000000</ele>
            <time>2008-09-11T16:22:08Z</time>
         </trkpt>
      </trkseg>
   </trk>
</gpx>
```

The user should then be able to select multiple trackpoints which have to be converted to a KML file and displayed in Google Maps.

I managed to upload the GPX file and wanted to display the trackpoints in a HTML select box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addTrackpoint(lat, lon)
{
    var x = document.getElementById("box");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = lat+", "+lon;
    x.add(option);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" onclick="for (var i = 0; i < <?php echo "$j"?>; i++) { 
 addTrackpoint(<?php echo "$lat[$i], $lon[$i]"?>);
 }">Trackpoints anzeigen</button>
<form action="select.htm">
  <p>
    <select id ="box" name="trackpoint_box" size="<?php echo "$j"?>" multiple>,
    </select>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
```

I can't figure out how to increment the $i now in order to display the different trackpoints because it's a PHP variable. But it also feels like my solution is just bad and complicated. Is there a more elegant solution to what I'm trying to accomplish?

---

Ok, I'm now trying to do this with AJAX and JSON. I have loaded and converted the XML:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

I try to load the JSON like this:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function loadJSON()
{
   var data_file = "<?php echo $json; ?>";
   var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();

.........
.........

 var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
```

How can I access my attributes now? I've tried this

```
document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML =  jsonObj.["@attributes"[5]].lat;
```

and it doesn't work. My JSON file looks like this for each trackpoint:

```
{"@attributes":
    {
    "lat":"48.105116667",
    "lon":"8.637700000"
    },
    "ele":"1000.000000",
    "time":"2008-09-11T16:25:52Z"
},
{"@attributes": .......
```

Comment: More elegant solution will be to use ajax to retrieve json object with data generated in php file.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to do this with AJAX and JSON now, can you look at my edited post please?

Comment: It works now, but only if I use var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data_file); instead of var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText); . This feels wrong, what am I needing that XMLHttpRequest for then?

Comment: I also want to display all my trackpoints in the HTML select box at once (via while-loop). But if I call my Javascript function by clicking a button, only one trackpoint is added to the select box. Help please.

Comment: jsonObj.["@attributes"][5].lat

Comment: Not entirely correct, in bracket notation you can't have that dot after jsonObj. Thanks anyway, I got it :)